# How to view parent state

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is example of my code.

```
        $stateProvider.state('filter', {
            url: "",
            templateUrl: 'Filter/widgets.roomer.filter.html',
            abstract: true,
            controller: 'RoomerFilterCtrl'
        })
            .state('mainRoomer', {
            url: "/main/r",
            views:
            {
                "RoomerView": {
                    templateUrl: 'Pages/Roomer/Main/pages.main.html',
                    controller: '',
                    parent: 'filter'
                }
            }
        })
```

I dont know, How to view filter state on page RoomerView
how to do this page 'filter' parent on mainRoomer and display it on the display?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please elaborate on problem in more detail

Comment: @charlietfl how to do this page 'filter' parent on mainRoomer and display it on the display?

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't clear at all. Do you have a `<ui-view>` in parent template for the child states to be inserted in?

Comment: I have no idea what that means. You are simply not providing enough information for anyone to help you.